# Unit testing cordova 'deviceready' event in angular application

Tags: angular, unit-testing, cordova, jasmine, observers

Unit testing cordova 'deviceready' event in angular application - I am using cordova to convert my angular 5 application to mobile app and I am able to do that. I am getting app version and build number details via cordova plugin once the deviceready event fired from cordova. I would like to test this scenario in unit testing. I have a route guard service in my app which will determine to allow user to login or redirect to different page based on the version. so in my guard I have the below code.

canActivate(): Observable | Promise | boolean {

```
if (this.utils.isMobile()) {
  return new Observable((observer) => {
    this.utils.getSomeData().subscribe((d) => {
      document.addEventListener('deviceready', () => {
        if (this.utils.compareData('5', '55')) {
          observer.next(true);
          observer.complete();
        } else {
          observer.next(false);
          observer.complete();
        }
      });
    });
  });
}

return true;
```

}

I had to use custom observer here in order to make my canActivate wait till the device ready event fire and comparison have completed. I am facing difficulties testing this. How do I fire this event and test the observer at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution - By Using jasmine marbles we can test this sort of Observables.

Samples here

https://stackblitz.com/edit/jasmine-marbles-testing?embed=1&file=src/basic.spec.ts&hideExplorer=1